# Installing entity form/view display config in custom module using options_select plugin

Tags: configuration

I am trying to provide a default content type, entity form display, entity view display and a list (text) field on module installation. Installation errors out (though the module is installed) because of a plugin not found exception for "options_select" which is a core plugin.

```
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "options_select" plugin does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 52 of /var/www/tx-sampling.zaner-bloser.com/webroot/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php).
```

This is caused by EntityViewBuilder not finding options_select in its object `$definitions` property, but why? `options_select` is a *core* plugin, and should be loaded? There is no dependency to add in config as the dependencies schema type does not have a "core" option.

This is probably due to something I am not understanding correctly with the YAML configuration I am providing given the following configuration in `module_name/config/install`:

`config_fail/config/install/node.type.config_fail.yml`:

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - menu_ui
    - config_fail
  enforced:
    module:
      - config_fail
third_party_settings:
  menu_ui:
    available_menus: {  }
    parent: ''
name: 'Config Fail'
type: config_fail
description: 'A content type installed by this module.'
help: ''
new_revision: true
preview_mode: 0
display_submitted: false
```

`config_fail/config/install/field.storage.node.field_blah.yml`:

```
    langcode: en
    status: true
    dependencies:
      module:
        - node
        - options
        - config_fail
      enforced:
        module:
          - config_fail
    id: node.field_blah
    field_name: field_blah
    entity_type: node
    type: list_string
    settings:
      allowed_values:
        -
          value: 'a'
          label: 'Option A'
        -
          value: 'b'
          label: 'Option B'
      allowed_values_function: ''
    module: options
    locked: true
    cardinality: 1
    translatable: true
    indexes: {  }
    persist_with_no_fields: false
    custom_storage: false
```

`config_fail/config/install/field.field.node.config_fail.field_blah.yml`:

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - field.storage.node.field_blah
    - node.type.config_fail
  module:
    - options
id: node.config_fail.field_blah
field_name: field_blah
entity_type: node
bundle: config_fail
label: 'Some Field'
description: 'Choose some option'
required: false
translatable: false
default_value: {  }
default_value_callback: ''
settings: {  }
field_type: list_string
```

`config_fail/config/install/core.entity_form_display.node.config_fail.default.yml`

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - field.field.node.config_fail.field_blah
    - node.type.config_fail
  module:
    - path
    - options
id: node.config_fail.default
targetEntityType: node
bundle: config_fail
mode: default
content:
  created:
    type: datetime_timestamp
    weight: 8
    region: content
    settings: {  }
    third_party_settings: {  }
  field_blah:
    weight: 0
    settings: {  }
    third_party_settings: {  }
    type: options_select
    region: content
  path:
    type: path
    weight: 10
    region: content
    settings: {  }
    third_party_settings: {  }
  promote:
    type: boolean_checkbox
    weight: 9
    region: content
    settings:
      display_label: true
    third_party_settings: {  }
  status:
    type: boolean_checkbox
    settings:
      display_label: true
    weight: 6
    region: content
    third_party_settings: {  }
  sticky:
    type: boolean_checkbox
    settings:
      display_label: true
    weight: 11
    region: content
    third_party_settings: {  }
  title:
    type: string_textfield
    weight: 0
    region: content
    settings:
      size: 60
      placeholder: ''
    third_party_settings: {  }
  uid:
    type: entity_reference_autocomplete
    weight: 7
    region: content
    settings:
      match_operator: CONTAINS
      size: 60
      placeholder: ''
    third_party_settings: {  }
hidden: {  }
```

`config_fail/config/install/core.entity_view_display.node.config_fail.default.yml`

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - field.field.node.config_fail.field_blah
    - node.type.config_fail
  module:
    - path
    - options
id: node.config_fail.default
targetEntityType: node
bundle: config_fail
mode: default
content:
  created:
    type: datetime_timestamp
    weight: 8
    region: content
    settings: {  }
    third_party_settings: {  }
  field_blah:
    weight: 0
    settings: {  }
    third_party_settings: {  }
    type: options_select
    region: content
  path:
    type: path
    weight: 10
    region: content
    settings: {  }
    third_party_settings: {  }
  promote:
    type: boolean_checkbox
    weight: 9
    region: content
    settings:
      display_label: true
    third_party_settings: {  }
  status:
    type: boolean_checkbox
    settings:
      display_label: true
    weight: 6
    region: content
    third_party_settings: {  }
  sticky:
    type: boolean_checkbox
    settings:
      display_label: true
    weight: 11
    region: content
    third_party_settings: {  }
  title:
    type: string_textfield
    weight: 0
    region: content
    settings:
      size: 60
      placeholder: ''
    third_party_settings: {  }
  uid:
    type: entity_reference_autocomplete
    weight: 7
    region: content
    settings:
      match_operator: CONTAINS
      size: 60
      placeholder: ''
    third_party_settings: {  }
hidden: {  }
```

`config_fail/config_fail.info.yml`:

```
name: 'Config Install fail'
type: module
core: 8.x
dependencies:
  - options
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the error message doesn't say which plugin type is missing.

But I think it is a field formatter plugin. You install a field type `list_string`:

```
 * @FieldType(
 *   id = "list_string",
 *   label = @Translation("List (text)"),
 *   description = @Translation("This field stores text values from a list of allowed 'value => label' pairs, i.e. 'US States': IL => Illinois, IA => Iowa, IN => Indiana."),
 *   category = @Translation("Text"),
 *   default_widget = "options_select",
 *   default_formatter = "list_default",
 * )
 */
```

The widget `options_select` is correct for the form mode, but not for the view mode. Here you can use the field formatter `list_default`.

Comment: I think I must have copy and pasted from a config export incorrectly. Thanks.